# Jquery UI: Arrow Slide effect error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[Here is the link for my code:](http://cdpn.io/AILgD)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" class="readmore">View about <span class="arrow">&#8594;</span></a>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><!-- jquery -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    var $readmore = $('.readmore');
    var $arrow = $('.arrow');

    $arrow.hide();
    $readmore.mouseenter(function (){ $('.arrow').toggle('slide')}).mouseleave(function (){
        $('.arrow').hide();
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The arrow slide from the left, which is correct.
**But the arrow starts from the bottom of the text, that does not I want.

It should start next to the text.**

Does anyone know why it happens?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Does anyone know why it happens?*

## Yes.

The **jQueryUI** `slide` effect creates a `<div>` around the element and performs its sliding on ***that***.

Why is ***that*** significant?  Because a `<div>` has a `display:` of `block` which creates a new line before and after by default, thus bringing it under the letters in the beginning of the animation.

*After the completion of the animation*, jQuery takes the original `display:` property of the element, whether `block`, `inline` or other, and restores it again.  Thus, bringing it back up to the same line again.

### [Reference for `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

*PS - I know you already accepted his answer but I thought you might want your actual question addressed as well.*

Comment: @user3112938 I would suggest accepting this answer as it actually addresses your question. It might also help other users as well if they're struggling with the same problem. Of course you can use my answer to solve your issue.

Comment: @ChrisBurton that was noble thank you. +1 for yours.  Teamwork.

Comment: looking at the above that's why I love this community, up vote to both of you

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way with CSS.

```
.readmore {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
span.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
}
```